# Creating a table as output

Tags: r, dplyr

I am completely stuck with creating a table out of a following code:

```
table4a = NY %>% 
  group_by(loan_type) %>% 
  summarize(
    min_amt = min(loan_amount, na.rm=TRUE), 
    max_amt = max(loan_amount, na.rm=TRUE), 
    mean_amt = mean(loan_amount, na.rm = TRUE))
table4a <- as.data.table(table4a)
```

Basically, I need the min, max, and mean of amounts by type of loan in a table, but it's just not working; I know I can create separate mins and maxs and means by loan type and plug them into a matrix, but I feel like there has got to be a better way! Please help!

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly here? Are you getting an error of some kind? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error; rather, I am trying to get an output that looks like a formatted table that I could export and include in a paper (i.e., with proper headers, etc.).

Comment: Well, since we can't run the code it's unclear what your current output is and what you need the output to look like. A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would make it much easier to help you. What exactly is a "proper" header?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give advice without more details, but look into the [gt package](https://gt.rstudio.com/), e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)
#install.packages("gt")
library(gt)

penguins %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(Minimum = as.numeric(min(flipper_length_mm)),
         Maximum = max(bill_length_mm),
         Mean = mean(bill_depth_mm)) %>% 
  select(species, Minimum, Maximum, Mean) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  gt(groupname_col = TRUE)
```

[image: example.png]

Comment: Thank you so much! gt package did the trick, indeed!

Comment: No problem, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you're problem is solved.